# JS constructor condition based on functions

Tags: javascript

In below snipped of code, I'm trying to make a call to `obj.b()` function only if that exists. How can I achieve this, code below is not working as expeected.

```
var obj = function () {
    var that = this;
    $('#test').fadeOut(1000, function () {
        if (that.b) {
            that.b('success');
        }
    });
}

var instance = new obj();

// This is not firing, how can I fix this?     
instance.b = function (a) {
    alert(a);
};
```

HTML

```
<div id="test">Test DIV</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Actually it is working in chrome now, here is url:
http://jsfiddle.net/Zkw7d/

Now I don't understand how it works because function b doesn't exist when we initialize constructor?

Comment: What you are doing is kind of like: Open a bank account, if money in account allow a withdrawal else don't. Put money in account. Why didn't I get any money?

Comment: Your code works just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/7TbUB/

Comment: @cookiemonster, thanks, how does it work because function b doesn't exist when constructor executes? Any explanation would be great - thanks

Comment: `fadeOut` is an asynchronous event I believe. This gives a chance for money to be deposited before before the withdrawal check.

Comment: `.fadeOut()` is asynchronous, so your constructor function exits and the `instance.b = func...` code runs long before the callback to `fadeOut()` is invoked.